# Styling of one label different from the rest when there's no code difference

Tags: css

i'm trying to fix the front page of my site so it's nice and centred, however i cant seem to find the problem wrong with it and why it's behaving the way it is.

The "Flexible" dates label isnt centered properly like it should be above the check box associated with it.

Anything to help me find what im missing is greatly appreciated

the site https://www.traveltradewinds.com/ttw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label, causing you problems, has the class `container` which has a `padding-left: 35px`.

Greeting, Mario

Answer (score 0):

With the current structure and css that checkbox cannot be aligned to center.
You could get some improvement using this:

```
.hb-form-table li:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: center;
}
.hb-form-table li:nth-child(3) label {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

It needs a lot a css to make that right especially considering responsiveness.